# Web Service Rest Error http 400

Tags: c#, rest, windows-mobile

I have a WebService that I use only for data.

Using the service:

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "maq/?v={v}",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        List<VoltaPDA> GetAllta(int v);
```

it works perfectly;

using this function in the same webService:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ped/?T={ti}&V={Vo}",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        List<Pedido> GetSub(string ti,string Vo);
```

I get the `error HTTP 400` The curious that the test through a browser directly both work, when I use them on my `Windows Mobile 6.5 application` the second function returns `HTTP 400 error`.;

Can you imagine what it might be?

Both access the same database`Sql Server 2012` , and the `WebService` hosted in `IIS 8.5`

webConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BD_S_V10ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=NUNO-PC;Initial Catalog=BD_S_V10;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  <globalization culture="pt-PT" uiCulture="pt-PT" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- REST -->
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServicePedido_v7.ServicePedido">
        <endpoint name="RestEndPoint" contract="WcfServicePedido_v7.IServicePedido" binding="webHttpBinding" address="" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <!-- REST -->
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Traces.svclog" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you include some details about how you test in browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is common that the Default `400` response is returned for Mime-Type mismatches and malformed requests (body and sometime URLs) from the client.

In this case, I would recommend checking the `Content-Type` header sent from the mobile application in the second request to make sure its something like `text/xml`.